# Open cart $ sign symbol price cache issue

Tags: php, mysql, css, opencart, browser-cache

I have open cart website have very weird problem when first time load page not able to see $ with price like just 39.00 after refresh page it will comes with $ like $39.00 what is issue not able to found please help.

After refresh If I will remove cache then again $ symbol disappeared

Please help

Comment: How about a link to the site?

Comment: I too have suffered through the same problem, though I found a solution for it. In the settings -> currency (store) edit the USD currency symbol to the symbol of currency you want and then its value to 1, after that in store settings you will find an option which will say autoupdate currency, turn that off and all set.

Comment: http://goo.gl/S3OiZ6

Comment: Hi, I already have same settings as you told I added link you can see same problem

Comment: add a sample code you have tried

Comment: Don't know in which code have problem Please check link if you help me something around